# Web Audio API play and stop button

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I've created a simple program where I push the 'play' button, it plays a series of sound (using a for loop). When I press the stop button, it stops the sound. However, when I press the 'play' button again, I need the sound to start for the beginning and what's currently happening is the old sound is getting played along with the new sound. I've tried `ctx.suspend()` and I've also tried `ctx.close()` which does not allow the `audiocontext` to restart. Any suggestions to make this play and stop buttons work? I've tried reloading the entire page when I press stop,but makes the page less user friendly and clunky (I want to add dropdown selections in the next version).

```
<script>
 
    try {
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      ctx = new AudioContext();
 
    }
    catch(e) {
      alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
    }

    var btn = document.querySelector('button');
    var btn_stop = document.querySelector('button_stop');
    const gainNode = ctx.createGain();

      

    fetch("http://localhost:8000/3saudio/C4v9.wav")
      .then(data => data.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => ctx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
        .then(decodedAudio => {
        c4 = decodedAudio;
        })

    function playnote(note, delay) {
      const playSound = ctx.createBufferSource();
      detune = 0;
      nt = c4;
      playSound.buffer = nt;
      var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
      var convolver = ctx.createConvolver();
      //console.log(nt)
      gainNode.gain.value = 1;
      gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, ctx.currentTime+delay);
      gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.0005, ctx.currentTime + 1.25 + delay);

     
      if (detune>0){
        playSound.detune.value = detune;

      }

      playSound.connect(gainNode).connect(ctx.destination);

      playSound.start(ctx.currentTime + delay);

    }

    function step51 () {
      var del = 0
      start = 12
      for (let i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
        playnote (keys[start+0],del + 0);
         playnote (keys[start+0],del + .25);
        playnote (keys[start+4],del + .5);
        playnote (keys[start+4],del + .75);
        playnote (keys[start+7],del + 1);
        playnote (keys[start+7],del + 1.25);
      }
    }

    
    document.querySelector('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

     keys = ['c4','c4','c4','c4', 'c4']

      if (ctx.state === "suspended") {
      ctx.resume();
      }
      step51()
    });


    btn_stop.addEventListener('click', function() {
      **ctx.suspend()
      //ctx.close()**

      **//window.location.reload()**
      //history.go(0);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AudioContext backs the entire audio graph of all the audio objects you create.  Normally, you'll only have one AudioContext per page, and you would only suspend it in circumstances where you don't want to play audio any time soon.

That is, rather that suspending the AudioContext, you should be [stopping your AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/stop).

Comment: Since I'm using a for loop to play discrete multiple sounds, it seems audiobuffersourcenode starts, plays the note, and stops and the cycle repeats until the for loop runs its course. Stopping the audiobuffersourcenode would have worked perfectly fine if I were trying to stop a continuous sine wave, In my scenario, it seems the for loop executes a lot faster than the playback, so I was wondering if discrete multiple sounds that the for loop instructs gets queued somewhere within Web Audio that I can somehow clear every time the 'stop' button is pressed.

Comment: @RajA Yes, as I said stop the AudioBufferSourceNode.

Comment: hey Brad - Thanks. I think I understand in principle, but still struggling a bit.  In my current code 'playSound' is the AudioBufferSourceNode. If I simply stop playSound, then I'm currently still hearing sounds (the loop function is feeding sounds to the  AudioBufferSourceNode). For me to stop all instances of the AudioBufferSourcenode, I need to track all of them into a variable, perhaps into an array, so that I can access all instances and stop them. I haven't gotten this to work either, but your guidance on whether I'm on the right track would help. So far, it feels like chasing electrons.

Comment: my sounds are very short (less than a second), so after one sound finishes, the program quickly moves onto the next sound, creating (I believe) another instance of the AudioBufferSourceNode.

Comment: @RajA Yes, and you need to keep an array or Set or something of every active AudioBufferSourceNode so you can stop them when you want.  Also note that your loop isn't waiting for anything... all those nodes are created essentially at the same time and scheduled for the future.

Comment: Thanks Brad, your solution worked! Really appreciate your guidance!!!